# D3.json setup cache to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, d3.js

I noticed that redrawing D3 elements with its json call (`d3.json`) don't want to be updated on IE9+. The reason for it is that json calls gets cached so the browser doesn't register as new data has been passed. Workaround for normal jQuery ajax calls is to set its property to cache: false, globally for all ajax calls:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

But how can I add it to `d3.json` calls, since its using own method for calling ajax? I succeeded with adding current timestamp after path:

```
var noCache = new Date().getTime();
d3.json(data + "?_=" + noCache)
```

but that is a bit lame way to do it... any suggestions how can I accomplish this? Or even better, how to setup this only if IE is running :)

Comment: I think it's probably easier to use JQuery here.

Comment: You are about right. I changed all calls from `d3.json` to `$.ajax`. Now I run into another problem, how to determine if browser is IE, or if browser is IE10-11 ? Since they removed the conditional comments `IF IE` from those versions. Still looking for an answer on web, but can't find a correct one

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I solved it by adding this code to the HEAD of the html document.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> 
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

However, this will prevent the caching of every object in a certain page, so be careful with images, fonts and others.

Comment: They just want to invalidate the cache for the AJAX request, not the cache for the entire page. You should only do this if you DON'T want your page cached AT ALL, which isn't ideal for sites where you have return visits. Cache is your friend!

Answer (score -1):

I had luck with this when using an API that didn't allow url parameters:

```
d3.json('your url', {
      cache: "no-store"
}).then(...
```