# Apache Tomcat - reads old file generated

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

In my servlet, I have generate a json file and write it in my `WebContent` folder.

```js
try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c:/users/user/workspace/poum/WebContent/answer.json")) {
            file.write(answerJSON);
        }
```

And in my jsp page, I call the file `answer.json` like this :

```js
d3.json("answer.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

The **problem** is that whenever I run the files, it always read old `json` files created. I checked the `answer.json` and it is updated with the latest content so I think the problem is not in the servlet.

I tried to run the file in IDE and also browser, both give the same result. 
I read that TTL configuration in tomcat might be the cause but I didn't change anything and default TTL is 5 seconds.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325220/d3-json-setup-cache-to-false or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053096/avoid-data-caching-when-using-d3-text

Comment: @user7294900 tried setting the no-cache in html head but still not working.

Comment: add to to url random number as :'answer.json?' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)

Answer (score 0):

Clear the Work folder and restart tomcat server. Compiled JSP files present in work folder.

```
<tomcat_directory/work>
```

Comment: I've done this but this thing still happens every time I restart the server. Usually first two times are okay, but after that it just won't work.